# Angular 1 data binding in $http promise not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page in which there exists a `add new user` button which shows an angular template to submit a form. form submit method is bound to `submit` method of `User Controller`. Form will be submitted to the server and the response will be fetched but the code `$scope.users = []` does not work. I've observed that `console.log($scope.users)` prints already listed users but I expect them to be removed from the view due to the `$scope.users = []` line but this does not happen. It seems that there is something wrong with data binding here.

`users.html`:

```
<div ng-controller = "UserController as uc">
    /***** table was omitted ********/ 
    <button type="button" ng-click="showForm()" class="btn btn-info">show new form</button>
    <div ng-show="pc.formVisible" ng-include="'assets/templates/new_user.html'"></div>
</div>
```

`new_user.html`:

```
<div class="new-user-form">
    <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="UserController">
        /******* form groups omitted *********/
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

`app.js`:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('MyStock', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {
        $scope.users = [];
        var formVisible = false;
        var cntl = this;
        cntl.formVisible = false;
        $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/customers', method='jsonp').success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        });

        $scope.showForm = function() {
            cntl.formVisible = true;
        };

        $scope.submit = function() {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url     : 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/customers',
                data: $scope.user,
                headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log($scope.users);
                $scope.users = [];
            });
        };

    }]);
})();
```

Comment: why you had `ng-controller="UserController"` twice, so that is assigning different context to `ng-include` template?

Comment: You're sending `data: $scope.user`, as in singular user.  Where is that in your controller?  I don't see it.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK `$scope.user` is OK since I've checked the request and response. The problem here is that, binding in the callback function does not work properly because changes there is not synced with view.

Comment: @PankajParkar you mean I should remove ng-controller from the `new_user.html` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have two controllers, thus changing the scope.
You have a parent controller, which is `UserController as uc` and a second controller, without an alias. The problem is they'll have different scopes.
When you hit submit, you're asking to the callback to clear the array from the unaliased controller.

Here's an example.
The first list and the last are the same, but they're differently referenced. One is directly binded with `vm.users`, the last one contains `$parent.vm`, telling to angular that it's using it's parent scope.

```js
(function() {
  
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller('MainController', ['$http', MainController]);
  
  function MainController($http) {
    
    var self = this;
    
    self.users = ['MNO', 'PQR', 'STU', 'VWX'];
    
    self.clearUsers = function() { self.users = []; };
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as vm">
  //Users from parent scope
  <div ng-repeat="user in vm.users"> {{user}} </div>
  <button ng-click="vm.clearUsers()"> Clear </button><br/>
  //Users from this scope
  <div ng-controller="MainController as mc">
    <div ng-repeat="user in mc.users"> {{user}} </div>
    <button ng-click="mc.clearUsers()">Clear</button>
  </div>
  //Clear users from parent scope
  <div ng-controller="MainController as mc2">
    <div ng-repeat="user in $parent.vm.users"> {{user}} </div>
    <button ng-click="$parent.vm.clearUsers()">Clear</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I see, but in my example, why `console.log($scope.users)` is working? As you said, they should have different scopes and $scope.users should be undefined there.

Comment: Not exactly, do you see this line `$http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/customers', method='jsonp').success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        });`, it's setting the users, so it'll never be undefined

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.users = [];
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

what this does is basically tell angular to recheck everything in the $scope and will apply the changes

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're hitting the `.then()` part of the promise?  I don't see a `.catch()` in your code.  Maybe the function failed?

Comment: @KKKKKKKK Yes! No it surely didn't fail because the line `console.log($scope.users);` is printing current listed users.

Comment: In Angular 1.3, evalAsync and applyAsync were added and these are preferred over the scope phase check and apply pattern.  See this [post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2751-scope-applyasync-vs-scope-evalasync-in-angularjs-1-3.htm) for more info.